# Probability of binary-drawing-game for two players

Tags: probability

Outline:

- 2 players
- Consecutive draws without putting anything back
- 5 total marbles
- 2 white, 3 black

Given solution:

-In the first game the white marble wins and for the person starting to draw the probability of winning is **3/5**
 -In another game the black marble wins and the probability of winning of the person starting to draw is **7/10**

My thoughts on first game:

The person starting to draw has a **2/5** chance of winning the game in the first round. If the first player draws a black marble the game continues. In the second round the second player has a **2/4** chance of winning. The second player also draw a black marble (the same chance for the first player that the game will continue). In the third round the first player has a **2/3** chance of winning. If the player draws a black marble the game continues. In the 4th round the second player is left with only white marbles, so the chance of winning is **2/2**.

For the first player I calculated:

**2/5** * **2/4** * **2/3** = **2/15** (compare to given solution **3/5**)

For the second game I calculated:

**3/5** * **3/4** * **3/3** = **9/20**  (compare to given solution **7/10**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first game you should **sum up** the probabilities when you read "**or**" and **mulitply** them (as you did) when you read "**and**". So, the person starting the game can win, if

1. He draws a white marble in the first draw, with probability $$2\over 5$$ **or**
2. If he does not draw a white marble **and** the second person does not draw a white marble **and** he draws a white marble in his second effort, with (total) probability $$\frac35\cdot\frac24\cdot\frac23$$

and there are no other possible ways, since otherwise the second person wins for sure in his subsequent draw. **Summing up** the probabilities of cases 1. and 2. we find that *the probability that the person starting the game wins*, is equal to $$\frac25+\frac35\cdot\frac24\cdot\frac23=\frac25+\frac15=\frac35$$

Analogous argumentation applies in the second game (where black marble wins)

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks allot!

Comment: @Spießbürger you are welcome!